# Is there a way to run SnowflakeOperator, SnowflakeHook locally in a non-Airflow script?

Tags: python, airflow, etl, airflow-2.x, snowflake-connector

I have some DAGs that use SnowflakeOperator and SnowflakeHook. Both of them are making connections to Snowflake using `snowflake_connection` input, which I have saved under `Admin > Connections` in Airflow.

```
SnowflakeHook(
    snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_connection",
    database='SOME_DB',
    schema='PUBLIC'
)
```

While this arrangement works inside the Airflow environment, I want to run the code as a regular script in my location machine. But it's unable to access that `snowflake_connection`, which I have saved inside Airflow. Is there any workaround to this?

Is there a way I can supply a connection string or username/password directly to `SnowflakeHook` and `SnowflakeOperator` to make a database connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the connection.

```py
conn = Connection(
    conn_type="gcpssh",
    login="cat",
    host="conn-host",
)
conn_uri = conn.get_uri()
with mock.patch.dict("os.environ", AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_CONN=conn_uri):
    assert "cat" == Connection.get("my_conn").login
```

For details, see: [Mocking variables and connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html)